# Disable opening parenthesis after method autocomplete in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio (based on IDEA, not Eclipse) and every time I select a method from the autocomplete popup with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it inserts the opening parenthesis automatically. I have `Settings>Editor>General>Smart Keys>Insert pair bracket` disabled.

Steps:

1. Open Java code (in my instance, an Android activity)
2. Move to a valid code region (say, inside onCreate)
3. Type `super.onC` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Expected: Editor contains `super.onCreate`
Actual: Editor contains `super.onCreate(`

How do I disable that opening parenthesis? It's ruining my normal typing flow because I always end up with an extra (. Even worse when I autocomplete a parameterless method in that it inserts both ().

Answer (score 8):

I don't think this is possible.

The only things you can do are:

Disable bracket, brace, etc completion.

[image]

Or disable code completion.

[image]

Comment: I've already disabled the matching option in your first screenshot and I don't want to just disable code completion.

Comment: Yes I know I can backspace, but when typing, I have to go back and fix it after the fact because I have years of experience typing it myself. Muscle memory and all that.

Comment: Yes this seems to be still an editor bug in 3.4.1 of Android Studio. It makes me crazy that this can't be turned off. I have, like you, disabled that paired brackets setting and still the editor creates a full bracket pair on parameterless methods and still puts in that open-bracket. This really brakes me down in speed. annoying.