# Android Studio / IDEA accept prompt no parentheses

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-studio-3.4, android-studio-3.5

This is Android Studio 3.4, there will be () after receiving the prompt
[image: Android Studio 3.4]

Below is Android Studio 3.5, no parentheses after accepting the prompt
[image: Android Studio 3.5]

I have modified it before, but I can't find it now. Where can I change it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable opening parenthesis after method autocomplete in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526696/disable-opening-parenthesis-after-method-autocomplete-in-android-studio)

Comment: in `Setting->Editor->General->Smart Keys`, checked `Insert paired brackets`, `insert pair quote`

Comment: But still the same as above

Comment: expectation `Container()` actual `Container`

Comment: Have you tried to restart your Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, I tried and tried Invalidate Caches / Restart